# Paypal IPN doesn't works (IPN was not sent) on my Website

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

**Paypal IPN Simulator** (https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/) not send informations on my Website (https website.com /subscription/ipn):

```
IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.
```

But it works on my another Website (https website2.com) without specific page for IPN controller:

```
IPN was sent and the handshake was verified.
```

Comment: Did you follow API requirements and pass in all *valid* parameters?

Comment: I get the impression that it comes from the domain name ...